# Скрыть кнопки JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, if

Есть кнопки такого вида:

```
<button value="мужская" data-option="Мужская одежда" class="control">Мужская одежда</button>
<button value="женская" data-option="Женская одежда" class="control">Женская одежда</button>
<button value="разное" data-option="Разное" class="control">Разное</button>
```

И массив: `Array['Разное', 'Женская одежда']`
Как при помощи JS скрыть кнопку, если значение `data-option` нет в списке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно все понял, то один из вариантов:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arr = ['Разное','Женская одежда'];
  $('button').each(function(){
      var data = $(this).attr('data-option');
      if (arr.indexOf(data) == -1) {
       $(this).hide();
      }
  });
 }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="мужская" data-option="Мужская одежда" class="control">Мужская одежда</button>
<button value="женская" data-option="Женская одежда" class="control">Женская одежда</button>
<button value="разное" data-option="Разное" class="control">Разное</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  /**
   * @type {NodeListOF<HTMLElement>}
   */
  let buttonList = document.getElementsByClassName('control')

  /**
   * @type {HTMLElement}
   */
  let button = null
  let arr = ['Разное', 'Женская одежда']

  for (
    button of buttonList
  ) {
    // let include = arr.includes(button.dataset.option)
    let include = -1 !== arr.indexOf(button.dataset.option)
    if (!include) {
      button.hidden = true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<button value="мужская" data-option="Мужская одежда" class="control">Мужская одежда</button>
<button value="женская" data-option="Женская одежда" class="control">Женская одежда</button>
<button value="разное" data-option="Разное" class="control">Разное</button>
```